# Header written as row in CSV Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have the following code which I am using to create and add a new row to a csv file.

```
def calcPrice(data):


   fieldnames = ["ReferenceID","clientName","Date","From","To","Rate","Price"]
   with open('rec2.csv', 'a') as csvfile:

     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
     writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerow(data)
```

return
However, it as the header as a new row as well. How can I prevent this? 
[image]

Here's a link to the gist with the whole code: https://gist.github.com/chriskinyua/5ff8a527b31451ddc7d7cf157c719bba

Comment: Dont write the header? Remove `writer.writeheader()`.

Comment: Please show the code where you use `calcPrice`.

Comment: Also share the output of the ```data``` variable. I believe that probably you have a row containing the header in ```data```.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I'm unable to add the whole code here. I've added a link to a gist.

Comment: Hello @michaeldel, please find my edit on the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the file already exists

```
import os

def calcPrice(data):

   filename = 'rec2.csv'
   write_header = not os.path.exists(filename)

   fieldnames = ["ReferenceID","clientName","Date","From","To","Rate","Price"]
   with open(filename, 'a') as csvfile:

     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
     if write_header:
        writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Hello, it does not work for initial execution of the function. It returns no header.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume there's a function we can call that will tell us whether we should write out the header or not, so the code would look like this:

```
import csv

def calcPrice(data):

   fieldnames = ["ReferenceID","clientName","Date","From","To","Rate","Price"]
   with open('rec2.csv', 'a') as csvfile:

       writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
       if should_write_header(csvfile):
           writer.writeheader()
       writer.writerow(data)
```

What will `should_write_header` look like?  Here are three possibilities.  For all of them, we will need to import the `io` module:

```
import io
```

The logic of all these functions is the same: we want to work out if the end of the file is the same as the beginning of the file.  If that is true, then we want to write the header row.

This function is the most verbose: it finds the current position using the file's [tell](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell) method, moves to the beginning of the file using its [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek) method, then runs `tell` again to see if the reported positions are the same.  If they are not it `seek`s back to the end of the file before returning the result.  We don't simply compare the value of `EOF` to zero because the Python docs state that the result of `tell` for text files does not necessarily correspond to the actual position of the file pointer.

```
def should_write_header1(fileobj):
    EOF = fileobj.tell()
    fileobj.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
    res = fileobj.tell() == EOF
    if not res:
        fileobj.seek(EOF, io.SEEK_SET)
    return res
```

This version *assumes* that while the `tell` method does not necessarily correspond to the position of the file pointer in general, `tell` will always return zero for an empty file.   This will probably work in common cases.

```
def should_write_header2(fileobj):
    return fileobj.tell() == 0
```

This version accesses the [tell](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.tell) method of the binary stream that `TextIOWrapper` (the text file object class) wraps.  For binary streams, `tell` is documented to return the actual file pointer position.  This is removes the uncertainty of `should_write_header2`, but unfortunately [buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.buffer) is not guaranteed to exist in all Python implementations, so this isn't portable.

```
def should_write_header3(fileobj):
    return fileobj.buffer.tell() == 0
```

So for 100% certainty, use `should_write_header1`.  For less certainty but shorter code, use one of the others.  If performance is a concern favour `should_write_header3`, because `tell` in binary streams is [faster](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#id3) than `tell` in text streams.

Comment: On the assumptions about tell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317588/will-textiowrapper-tell-reliably-return-zero-at-the-beginning-of-a-file