# Will TextIOWrapper.tell reliably return zero at the beginning of a file?

Tags: python, file-io, cpython, python-internals

The docs for [TextIOBase.tell](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell), from which `TextIOWrapper` inherits, state

> Return the current stream position as an opaque number. The number does not usually represent a number of bytes in the underlying binary storage.

I am wondering, whether it will always return zero in the specific case that the file pointer is at the beginning of the file?

I wrote a small, non-exhaustive, script to check some obvious scenarios, which returned zero for each  case:

```py
import io
import os


rmodes = ['a', 'a+', 'r', 'r+']
wmodes = ['w', 'w+', 'a', 'a+', 'x', 'x+']


for m in wmodes:
    with open('empty.txt', m) as f:
        print(m, f.tell())

    os.system('rm empty.txt')


for m in rmodes:
    open('not-empty.txt', 'w').write('abc\n')

    with open('non-empty.txt', m) as f:
        f.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
        print(m, f.tell())

    if m == 'r':continue    # avoid exception

    with open('non-empty.txt', m) as f:
        f.truncate()
        print(m, f.tell())
```

I *believe* [this code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/83fc70159b24f5b11a5ef87c9b05c2cf4c7faeba/Modules/_io/textio.c#L2023) is used to generate the return value of `tell`

```
static PyObject *
textiowrapper_build_cookie(cookie_type *cookie)
{
    unsigned char buffer[COOKIE_BUF_LEN];

    memcpy(buffer + OFF_START_POS, &cookie->start_pos, sizeof(cookie->start_pos));
    memcpy(buffer + OFF_DEC_FLAGS, &cookie->dec_flags, sizeof(cookie->dec_flags));
    memcpy(buffer + OFF_BYTES_TO_FEED, &cookie->bytes_to_feed, sizeof(cookie->bytes_to_feed));
    memcpy(buffer + OFF_CHARS_TO_SKIP, &cookie->chars_to_skip, sizeof(cookie->chars_to_skip));
    memcpy(buffer + OFF_NEED_EOF, &cookie->need_eof, sizeof(cookie->need_eof));

    return _PyLong_FromByteArray(buffer, sizeof(buffer),
                                 PY_LITTLE_ENDIAN, 0);
}
```

Clearly it computes more than just the offset of the file pointer from the beginning of the file.  But will this code always return zero at the beginning of a file?  What might be the circumstances in which it would not?

I am

- aware that the behaviour is implementation-dependent and not guaranteed by the docs
- asking specifically about the behaviour in text files, not binary
- not asking "how do I know if I am at the beginning of a file in Python?"
- not asking for alternative means of obtaining the position of the file pointer

Comment: Most cases (all in your loop over `wmodes` that create a new file each time) call the system `lseek` (see `_io_FileIO_tell_impl` which calls `portable_lseek` in `fileio.c`) and that is returned as the value of `tell`. The function you linked is used in some of the cases, though. Can't say much else about fileobjects in CPython since I've never looked into them but, I can't see why `tell` wouldn't reliably return 0 here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DimitrisFasarakisHilliard - would you like to make it an answer?

Comment: I don't feel like it really answers the question, that's why I added it as a comment :-). If you feel it suffices (for you) go ahead and add it as a self answer. (and if not, put a bounty on it!)