# Checking if csv file is empty even with one header

Tags: python, csv

When I iterate through all CSV files in a single directory, I want to check if my files are actually empty or not, even with only header row which it will be considered as empty file.

I tried using
`if os.stat(filename).st_size == 0:`
files that with only header row will never be considered as empty files. What command should I use instead?

I want to make sure that when first row in CSV files is also considered as empty file.

Comment: Do you know how large the header is?

Comment: If you don't mind opening the files, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61294190/5320906) might be useful.

Comment: There's is no single command to do this — you're going to have to read some or all of each file.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi header has 3 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code. If two not empty lines can be read from file (header plus first data row), it is considered not empty.

It works because `readline()` returns empty string if end of file is encountered, and empty string is considered falsy in Python.

Advantage of this solution is that at most 2 lines are read from each file, so it should work quickly even when files are large.

```
import glob


def has_data_rows(fname):
    with open(fname) as file:
        return file.readline() and file.readline()


for fname in glob.glob('./*.csv'):
    if has_data_rows(fname):
        print('file {} has data rows'.format(fname))
    else:
        print('file {} is empty or has only header row'.format(fname))
```